# Move object from center to corner with animation on javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Its a basic flash animation that i want.But i dont want to use flash.

First i want to see big logo on intro screen and it move to left corner as smaller with animation.

What is the best practice to do this.Any sample ?

Thx

Comment: You're going to need to include code. Going to let someone else post the "what have you tried?" link.

Comment: @AndrewPeacock: http://whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

[here is jsfiddle example to play with, just click](http://jsfiddle.net/YBAaM/)

css:

```
.logo { position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; }
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //when document ready
  $('.logo').animate({'left':'960px'},1000); //1000 = 1second


  //click animation
  $('.logo').click(function(){
     $(this).animate({'left':'960px'},1000); // you can set left/top or you can do it with margins
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

[jquery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) with all the right values could do this pretty easily.